# Is anyone using Node.js as an actual web server?

Tags: web-server, node.js

I am trying to convince myself to pick it up and start developing with it, but I want to know if anyone has expected stability issues or anything of the sort.

I understand it isn't "production" quality, like Apache or IIS. I figure for a small site, it should be fine (max of 200 concurrent connections). Should I assume this?

Comment: I think this should constantly be updated with new answers. Especially  up to date answers on the biggest large scale use of Node.JS.

Comment: I agree. I really would love to see how many people are truly using it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Plurk.com uses Node.js for their Comet engine, they have a fairly high traffic load too.

[Blog post about Plurk using Node.js](http://amix.dk/blog/post/19490)

Answer (score 7):

Since node.js has not been around long enough to have satisfied the greater community that it's stable and secure, many production deployments use [Apache](http://arguments.callee.info/2010/04/20/running-apache-and-node-js-together/) or [nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009324/node-js-nginx-and-now) as a web server that proxies http requests to node running on a different port that is not accessible from the machine's public IP address.

Also [forever](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/keep-a-nodejs-server-up-with-forever) may be able to help with the node stability issue.

Comment: +1 For pointing to "Forever". I'm also looking into "Supervisor" and "Upstart", e.g. http://cuppster.com/2011/05/18/using-supervisor-with-upstart

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer to your question but very related in terms of hosting node.js apps: two Heroku-like providers using node.js/JavaScript instead of Ruby, both in the beta/invite stage (as of mid-March 2011):

- http://www.nodesocket.com/
- http://www.nodejitsu.com/

Answer (score 2):

Looks like they pulled off some success stories from big companies. A good sign.

[NodeJS.org](http://nodejs.org/) now promotes articles from major companies [Microsoft](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/interoperability/), [eBay](http://www.ebaytechblog.com/2011/11/30/announcing-ql-io/), [LinkedIn](http://venturebeat.com/2011/08/16/linkedin-node/) and [Yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2011/11/yahoo-announces-cocktails-%E2%80%93-shaken-not-stirred/).

I wonder what Google will do... They may already have evented I/O worked out behind the scenes. Or maybe they are just biding their time before they put their good name behind a product.

Comment: Google has produced [Go](http://golang.org/) which, while not event-driven, provides concurrency easily.

Answer (score 1):

I use it as a [reverse proxy](http://steve.org.uk/Software/node-reverse-proxy/) in front of my sites - none are obscenely busy sites, but my [image portfolio](http://edinburgh-portraits.com/) gets a lot of traffic.

I've not seen any random strangeness, crashes, or reliability issues to date.

Comment: Note that security is the big unknown. It [started out with buffer overflow vulnerabilities](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/2940300/1). Whether it is all resolved is not yet known, but anyone implementing should keep their Node.JS up to date, in case there are some security items that got missed. (I'm no security expert)

Comment: Is it faster then nginx or another proxyes you tried?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is faster - but I know it isn't slow - but it is definitely 100% more flexible.